# How to filter for "greater than equal" or "less than equal" using the Cumulocity AngularJS WebSDK

Tags: angularjs, cumulocity

we are using the latest AngularJS WebSDK and use the c8yDevices.listQuery method in order to fetch data.

Now we wanted to implement filters which work if we use greater than or less than queries as follows:

__filter: {kpn_Temperature: {__gt: 30}}

If we use "greater than or equal" using __ge or "less than or equal" using __le, the filter queries will be converted to very strange requests against Cumulocity:

http://localhost:9000/inventory/managedObjects?pageSize=100&q=$filter%3D(__ge+eq+40)&withTotalPages=true

In comparison a URL with a working greater than filter:
http://localhost:9000/inventory/managedObjects?pageSize=100&q=$filter%3D(kpn_Temperature+gt+20)&withTotalPages=true

How do I need to configure the __filter object in order to be able to filter for "greater than or equal", or "lesser than or equal"?